# Playing audios from local storage to JavaScript in localhost

Tags: javascript, html, audio, localhost

When viewing my page in localhost I find it impossible to access files from my device storage.

```
<audio src="file:///path/to/img"/>
```

It always return an error, saying unsupported source

Comment: Webpages don't have access to your PC's file system, it is a fundamental security feature

Comment: So there is no way to access the files?. Or a way to request user permission to read files?